# Optimizing indexes for a dependent subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a query with dependent subqueries and would like to know Which fields should be indexed for maximum performance? The query (below) shows all orders of anyone with "smi" in their name, for example. The query is grabbing the customer name from the customer table by shared cust# in the orders and customer tables. I am pretty much stuck with this query as it is mostly auto-generated from a php development tool. So, given those constraints, which fields should be indexed to get the best performance?

```
SELECT *, (SELECT CONCAT(customers.last, ', ', customers.first)
FROM customers WHERE customers.cust_num = orders.cust_num) AS c_lastname 
FROM orders WHERE (SELECT CONCAT(customers.last, ', ', customers.first) 
FROM customers WHERE customers.cust_num = orders.cust_num) LIKE '%smi%' 
ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

EXPLAIN gives me:

```
"1" "PRIMARY"   "orders"    "index" \N  "PRIMARY"   "4" \N  "20"    "Using where"
"3" "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY"    "customers" "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "orders.cust_num"   "1" ""
"2" "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY"    "customers" "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "orders.cust_num"   "1" ""
```

Comment: As the Answers point out, the only optimization hope is to scan `customers` _first_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the query would be more straightforward like this:

```
SELECT o.*, CONCAT(c.`last`, ', ', c.`first`) AS cName
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN customers AS c ON o.cust_num = c.cust_num
WHERE c.`last` LIKE '%smi%' OR c.`first` LIKE '%smi%'
ORDER BY order_id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

or, similar to Gordon's:

```
SELECT o.*, c.Name
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT cust_num, CONCAT(`last`, ', ', `first`) AS Name 
    FROM customers
    WHERE `last` LIKE '%smi%' OR `first` LIKE '%smi%'
) AS c ON o.cust_num = c.cust_num
ORDER BY order_id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

The first avoids a subquery, but the latter will reduce redundant CONCAT operations on orders for the same customer; which performs better may depend on the actual data in the table.

...and to echo Gordon, there is not much you can do about "%smi%"; MySQL doesn't index strings from the middle, so that leading wildcard basically eliminates the possibility of index use.

Comment: (Your second one can avoid re-concatenating the name; it is readily available from the subquery.)

Comment: @RickJames oh, that is a copy-paste error; until I edit it in a moment the second one would fail due to not having access to those fields to concatenate.

Comment: This worked and also answered the question about indexing. I will say just for those reading that when I tested the first query vs. my original query with sqlslap multiple times simulating concurrent users, the speed of the query was the same as the new one

Comment: If your original query performed about the same as my first suggestion, the MySQL optimizer likely "converted" it to the same kind of query. Had your "join" condition been more complicated, it could've ended up running those subqueries as correlated ones; meaning it would have effectively executed the subquery separately behind the scenes for each result of the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by rewriting the query as:

```
SELECT o.*, c.last_name
FROM (SELECT cust_name, CONCAT(c.last, ', ', c.first) as c_lastname
      FROM customers c
      HAVING c_lastname LIKE '%smi%'
     ) c JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.cust_num = c.cust_num
ORDER BY order_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

I don't think there is much you can do about the `like`, unless you really mean `liike 'smi%'` instead.

But, you can then create an index on `orders(cust_num)` for the `join`.  There isn't much you can do about the outer `order by`.